# ValueError: Expected singleton: res.partner(1, 12, 29, 30, 36) - res.partner - Odoo v10 community

Tags: python, odoo, odoo-8, odoo-10

I'm inheriting `res.partner` model, this is a migration from v8 to v10 community.

The offending methods look like this:

```
@api.depends('company_id')
def _get_country_code(self):
    """
    Return the country code of the user company. If not exists, return XX.
    """
    #context = dict(self._context or {})
    for partner in self:
        user_company = self.env['res.company'].browse(self.company_id)
        #NOTE: replace code name with your real field name where you want to see value 
        partner.code = user_company.partner_id and user_company.partner_id.country_id \
            and user_company.partner_id.country_id.code or 'XX'

@api.multi
def _get_uid_country(self): 
    """ Return a dictionary of key ids as invoices, and value the country code
    of the user company.
    """
    res = {}.fromkeys(self._get_country_code()) 
    return res
```

Now very time I click on a client, or supplier (res.partner), it throws me this:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/home/kristian/.virtualenvs/odoov10/lib/python2.7/site-packages/odoo-10.0rc1c_20161005-py2.7.egg/odoo/http.py", line 638, in _handle_exception
return super(JsonRequest, self)._handle_exception(exception)
File "/home/kristian/.virtualenvs/odoov10/lib/python2.7/site-packages/odoo-10.0rc1c_20161005-py2.7.egg/odoo/http.py", line 675, in dispatch
result = self._call_function(**self.params)
File "/home/kristian/.virtualenvs/odoov10/lib/python2.7/site-packages/odoo-10.0rc1c_20161005-py2.7.egg/odoo/http.py", line 331, in _call_function
return checked_call(self.db, *args, **kwargs)
File "/home/kristian/.virtualenvs/odoov10/lib/python2.7/site-packages/odoo-10.0rc1c_20161005-py2.7.egg/odoo/service/model.py", line 119, in wrapper
return f(dbname, *args, **kwargs)
File "/home/kristian/.virtualenvs/odoov10/lib/python2.7/site-packages/odoo-10.0rc1c_20161005-py2.7.egg/odoo/http.py", line 324, in checked_call
result = self.endpoint(*a, **kw)
File "/home/kristian/.virtualenvs/odoov10/lib/python2.7/site-packages/odoo-10.0rc1c_20161005-py2.7.egg/odoo/http.py", line 933, in __call__
return self.method(*args, **kw)
File "/home/kristian/.virtualenvs/odoov10/lib/python2.7/site-packages/odoo-10.0rc1c_20161005-py2.7.egg/odoo/http.py", line 504, in response_wrap
response = f(*args, **kw)
File "/home/kristian/odoov10/odoo-10.0rc1c-20161005/odoo/addons/web/controllers/main.py", line 862, in call_kw
return self._call_kw(model, method, args, kwargs)
File "/home/kristian/odoov10/odoo-10.0rc1c-20161005/odoo/addons/web/controllers/main.py", line 854, in _call_kw
return call_kw(request.env[model], method, args, kwargs)
File "/home/kristian/.virtualenvs/odoov10/lib/python2.7/site-packages/odoo-10.0rc1c_20161005-py2.7.egg/odoo/api.py", line 681, in call_kw
return call_kw_multi(method, model, args, kwargs)
File "/home/kristian/.virtualenvs/odoov10/lib/python2.7/site-packages/odoo-10.0rc1c_20161005-py2.7.egg/odoo/api.py", line 672, in call_kw_multi
result = method(recs, *args, **kwargs)
File "/home/kristian/.virtualenvs/odoov10/lib/python2.7/site-packages/odoo-10.0rc1c_20161005-py2.7.egg/odoo/models.py", line 2995, in read
values[name] = field.convert_to_read(record[name], record, use_name_get)
File "/home/kristian/.virtualenvs/odoov10/lib/python2.7/site-packages/odoo-10.0rc1c_20161005-py2.7.egg/odoo/models.py", line 5171, in __getitem__
return self._fields[key].__get__(self, type(self))
File "/home/kristian/.virtualenvs/odoov10/lib/python2.7/site-packages/odoo-10.0rc1c_20161005-py2.7.egg/odoo/fields.py", line 860, in __get__
self.determine_value(record)
File "/home/kristian/.virtualenvs/odoov10/lib/python2.7/site-packages/odoo-10.0rc1c_20161005-py2.7.egg/odoo/fields.py", line 969, in determine_value
self.compute_value(recs)
File "/home/kristian/.virtualenvs/odoov10/lib/python2.7/site-packages/odoo-10.0rc1c_20161005-py2.7.egg/odoo/fields.py", line 924, in compute_value
self._compute_value(records)
File "/home/kristian/.virtualenvs/odoov10/lib/python2.7/site-packages/odoo-10.0rc1c_20161005-py2.7.egg/odoo/fields.py", line 916, in _compute_value
getattr(records, self.compute)()
File "/home/kristian/odoov10/gilda/l10n_ve_fiscal_requirements/model/partner.py", line 90, in _get_uid_country
res = {}.fromkeys(self._get_country_code()) #ids, cr, uid, context=context)
File "/home/kristian/odoov10/gilda/l10n_ve_fiscal_requirements/model/partner.py", line 68, in _get_country_code
user_company = self.env['res.company'].browse(self.company_id)
File "/home/kristian/.virtualenvs/odoov10/lib/python2.7/site-packages/odoo-10.0rc1c_20161005-py2.7.egg/odoo/fields.py", line 854, in __get__
record.ensure_one()
File "/home/kristian/.virtualenvs/odoov10/lib/python2.7/site-packages/odoo-10.0rc1c_20161005-py2.7.egg/odoo/models.py", line 4783, in ensure_one
raise ValueError("Expected singleton: %s" % self)
ValueError: Expected singleton: res.partner(1, 33, 8, 18, 22, 23)
```

I think it has to do with this line `user_company = self.env['res.company'].browse(self.company_id)` but I'm not 100% sure.

Any ideas?

**EDIT**

Old API original methods:

```
def _get_country_code(self, cr, uid, context=None):
    """
    Return the country code of the user company. If not exists, return XX.
    """
    context = context or {}
    user_company = self.pool.get('res.users').browse(
        cr, uid, uid, context=context).company_id
    return user_company.partner_id and user_company.partner_id.country_id \
        and user_company.partner_id.country_id.code or 'XX'

def _get_uid_country(self, cr, uid, ids, field_name, args, context=None):
    """ Return a dictionary of key ids as invoices, and value the country code
    of the user company.
    """
    context = context or {}
    res = {}.fromkeys(ids, self._get_country_code(cr, uid,
                                                  context=context))
    return res
```

Comment: It's hard to understand the requirements. You're working in partners but speak of "user company". What is the requirement for this compute method?

Comment: And could you please add the old API style methods, too?

Comment: Hi @CZoellner yes, this module wasn't made by me, lol, I'm just migrating it, it's from a localization

Comment: Hi, edited my question, with original old api functions, please have a look, thank You!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've tried to shorten it a bit:

```py
uid_country = fields.Char(
    string="Country Code of Current User",
    compute="_get_uid_country")

@api.multi
@api.depends('company_id')  # there should be a better trigger field
def _get_uid_country(self):
    """ Compute country code by current users company """
    country_code = self.env.user.company_id.partner_id.country_id.code or 'XX'
    for partner in self:
        partner.update({'uid_country': country_code})
```

This should be enough. Seems to me, that there is no real trigger field and the computed field will be computed every time a partner is called. But it should work.

Comment: Thank You so much, it throws this: return self._fields[key].__set__(self, value)
KeyError: 'code' , hmmm, it's on this line 'partner.update({'code': country_code})' hmmm

Comment: Should I open a newquestion for that?

Comment: No, i used `code` because you've used it, too. I don't know the name of the computed field. Maybe you can tell me, then i will update my answer.

Comment: Hi, Thank You, since it's not made by me, I think the field is 'uid_country', I tried with that, but it says 'NoneType object is not iterable', :/

Comment: res = {}.fromkeys(self._get_country_code()) 
TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not iterable

Comment: where did you get `res = {}.fromkeys(self._get_country_code())` from? That's not in my answer.

Comment: Yes, I know, but it's the code that calls _get_country_code, it is present in my question

Comment: You just need my code, nothing more except the field definition, which i will edit in now.

Comment: Cool, so, on 'uid_country', which computes the function that calls _get_uid_country function, I'll need to change 'compute=' attribute to Your function, ok, going to try, sorry, these modules have some weird stuff on them :/

Comment: The origin code shows `_get_uid_country` as the compute function, you can see it in the parameters.

Comment: Yes, well, I've put _get_country_code, I'll change it now, but it's the same result :) , Thank You so much xD, works prefectly! Prost

Answer (score 1):

You can try replacing this line:

```
user_company = self.env['res.company'].browse(self.company_id)
```

with this

```
user_company = self.env['res.company'].browse(partner.company_id)
```

and then let us know

Comment: Hi, it says 'ProgrammingError: can't adapt type 'res.company'' :/

Comment: I've edited my question, with original old API methods, thank You

Comment: Try this:

`user_company = self.env['res.company'].browse(partner.company_id.id)`

Answer (score 1):

When you use `@api.multi` self is a RecordSet :

> RecordSet can have 0 or 1 or more records when you use self.getSomeThing this works if the RecordSet have one record, but if it have more than one an exception is raised because it will not know witch record you want to ask.
>   so if you use `@api.multi` try to always to loop the recordSet.
>   @api.depends is also like @api.multi the self is a RecordSet.

```
for rec in self :
     rec.getSomeThing
```

> or use `@api.one` here the self is always one Record but is not recommanded because it call the getSomeThing according to the number of records in your view, so for form view it's not a problem because it has only one but for tree view you can imagine.

Answer (score 0):

You should try the _get_uid_country function as:

`for record in self.browse():
    result = {}.fromkeys(record._get_country_code(), False)`

Comment: I see the purpose behind this answer, but since the aimed platform is odoo 10, there are two things (maybe assumptions) here that are just wrong. At first `self` is a `RecordSet` with all needed database records as python instances already. There is no need to browse anything here. And second there is no need to return anything in odoo 10 compute methods anymore. But i admit that it's hard to realize `_get_uid_country` as a compute method.

Comment: @CZoellner Thanks for your info.